# How to rename a MOUNT (mounted shared folder from Windows named mnt)

Tags: linux, unix

How to rename a MOUNT (mounted shared folder from Windows named mnt)?

How to rename mnt?

This is the command I used on linux command tool to mount my Shared folder from windows pc to a linux controller.

```
# mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypassword //10.80.50.50/Share /mnt
```

So my mounted Shared folder is now name mnt... How to rename it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Unmount:

  ```
  umount /mnt
  ```
- Create another folder:

  ```
  mkdir /my_new_mount
  ```
- Mount again:

  ```
  mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypassword //10.80.50.50/Share /my_new_mount
  ```
- Update in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks for your super fast ultra hydep response. :) Like a flash thanks alot!